# C# Metro stream Video (TS) via a HTTP

Tags: c#, video-streaming, microsoft-metro

I'm interested in streaming a video feed via HTTP to my Metro app that's coded in C#. Does anyone have any examples on how to achieve this using the player framework?

thanks

Comment: [What](http://blogs.iis.net/vsood/archive/2012/03/12/announcing-smooth-streaming-client-sdk-beta-for-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx) [have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465176.aspx) [you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965244(v=vs.85).aspx) found? The client part shouldn't be that hard. For a "streaming video server", type that into your favourite search engine and try a few or read about them. Concrete questions only please. :)

Comment: I'm not after the server side, I was after the client side and it wouldn't be using Microsoft's smooth streaming tech (you have to have it installed on the video server). I'll have another look around. thanks

Comment: Play To is similar to Apple's airplay. i didnt find a link to something called the Player Framework but i can't see any examples but i'll continue to look.